# Image Upload using angular js and spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, image-upload

I was stuck in a problem to upload image using angular js and spring mvc.
I have visited many examples but still problem not resolved. I am not able to understand where I was wrong.
I have tried it many times but getting 500 error:

```
<h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.27</h3></body></html>","status":500,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:8084/SAMA/home/uploadPhoto","params":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Here is what I tried:

JSP page:

```
<body ng-app="RegisterApp" ng-controller="RegisterController">
<form ng-submit="submitRegisterInfo1()" name="regForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="cust-button" />
</form>
</body>
```

Angular js code:

```
var registerInfo = angular.module('RegisterApp', []);
registerInfo.controller('RegisterController',['$scope', '$http', '$location', 
function($scope, $http, $location)
{
    $scope.submitRegisterInfo1 = function()
    {
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        alert(fd);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://' + host + '/SAMA/home/uploadPhoto',
            params: fd,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        });
    };
});
registerInfo.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Spring Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadPhoto(MultipartHttpServletRequest filePath)
{
    //Some Code
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadPhoto(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    //Some Code
    return "";
}
```